# monitoring ping status of a server

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new to zabbix. Basically I want to monitor whether a ping becomes unresponsive of a server.
So to try it out, I picked www.google.com(103.7.200.87) to monitor the status of the ping.

But my configuration gave me this error.

```
get value from agent failed. cannot connect to [[103.7.200.87:10050]:[4] interrupted system call
```

This is what I have in the log file

```
2363:20150419:202143.796 cannot send list of active checks to [127.0.0.1]: host [Zabbix server] not found
2363:20150419:202343.898 cannot send list of active checks to [127.0.0.1]: host [Zabbix server] not found
2368:20150419:202411.730 fping failed: (null): can't create socket (must run as root?) : Permission denied
2376:20150419:202413.581 item "Google:icmpping" became not supported: fping failed: (null): can't create socket (must run as root?) : Permission denied
2376:20150419:202413.581 item "Google:icmppingloss" became not supported: fping failed: (null): can't create socket (must run as root?) : Permission denied
2376:20150419:202413.581 item "Google:icmppingsec" became not supported: fping failed: (null): can't create socket (must run as root?) : Permission denied
2356:20150419:202503.602 Zabbix agent item "system.localtime" on host "Google" failed: another network error, wait for 15 seconds
```

How should I resolve the error so that I can monitor the status of the ping of www.google.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that Zabbix is trying to look for an agent on 103.7.200.87 to connect to.

You'll want to use a simple check (icmpping)if you're just trying to ping a server without an agent.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks